# Highcharts same types of data with different series

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that shows the number of ratings 1 - 5 (1 Star, 2 Stars, etc.) an item has received, but I can't get it to display properly on the graph. This is the closest I have come to getting it display:

```
$('#chartdiv').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: "column"
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My Ads'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["1 Star", "2 Stars", "3 Stars", "4 Stars", "5 Stars"],
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            rotation: -20,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "Number of Ratings"
        }
    },
    series: [{
        "name": "1 Stars",
        "data": [10]
    }, {
        "name": "2 Stars",
        "data": [42]
    }, {
        "name": "3 Stars",
        "data": [60]
    }, {
        "name": "4 Stars",
        "data": [110]
    }, {
        "name": "5 Stars",
        "data": [100]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        //shared: true,
        crosshairs: false
    },
    series: series,
});
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image: Output]

How can I get it to look like that, but have have all the labels? I have also tried using a dataset like this:

```
[{
    "data": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
    "data": [0, 42, 0, 0, 0]
}, {
    "data": [0, 0, 60, 0, 0]
}, {
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 110, 0]
}, {
    "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 100]
}],
```

And it gives me this output

[image: Graph 2]

Those are spaced too far apart, so basically how can I get this to display like the first image, but have one item in each data set?

**------------**
**UPDATE:**
**------------**

This series works for me. The only Issue I have is it says `Series 1: 10` in the tooltip (Image is a little blurry, sorry).

[image: Graph 3]

```
"series": [{
        "data": [{
                "name": "1 Star",
                "y": 10
            }, {
                "name": "2 Stars",
                "y": 42
            }, {
                "name": "3 Stars",
                "y": 60
            }, {
                "name": "4 Stars",
                "y": 110
            }, {
                "name": "5 Stars",
                "y": 100
            }]
    }],
```

Comment: `The only Issue I have is it says Series 1: 10 in the tooltip` -- what would you like it to say?

Comment: Which values should in the tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use these settings(Try to play with pointWidth - width of the column)

```
     plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointWidth: 50//width of the column
            },
            column: {
                        pointPadding: 0,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
        },
     tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
        return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>'+ '</b>, in series '+ this.series.name;
    }
```

Update - I have added custom tooltip

Comment: @RyanNaddy I have updated my answer.You need to use custom "tooltip".Please see my code again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I am looking for using this series:

```
"series": [{
        "name": "Number of Ratings",
        "data": [{
                "name": "1 Star",
                "y": 10
            }, {
                "name": "2 Stars",
                "y": 42
            }, {
                "name": "3 Stars",
                "y": 60
            }, {
                "name": "4 Stars",
                "y": 110
            }, {
                "name": "5 Stars",
                "y": 100
            }]
    }],
```